# How to convert HTML to RTF in Java?

Tags: java

(I'm looking for a open source library)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iText I believe has an RTF capability as well as pdf.

http://itextpdf.com/

http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/itext/creating-pdf-rtf-or-document-from-a-java-class-at-ru-2.html

Comment: The question is not how do you create an RTF document in Java, it's how do you *convert* an HTML document to RTF.  iText is great, but it just provides the ability to create/edit documents, not convert from one format to another.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert HTML to RTF using basic Java APIs `RTFEditorKit` and `HTMLEditorKit`.
It is not converting new line tags like `<br/>` and `<p>` to new line character equivalent in RTF. I have applied external fix for that as shown in following Java code.

```
private static String convertToRTF(String htmlStr) {

    OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    HTMLEditorKit htmlEditorKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
    RTFEditorKit rtfEditorKit = new RTFEditorKit();
    String rtfStr = null;

    htmlStr = htmlStr.replaceAll("<br.*?>","#NEW_LINE#");
    htmlStr = htmlStr.replaceAll("</p>","#NEW_LINE#");
    htmlStr = htmlStr.replaceAll("<p.*?>","");
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlStr.getBytes());
    try {
        Document doc = htmlEditorKit.createDefaultDocument();
        htmlEditorKit.read(is, doc, 0);
        rtfEditorKit .write(os, doc, 0, doc.getLength());
        rtfStr = os.toString();
        rtfStr = rtfStr.replaceAll("#NEW_LINE#","\\\\par ");
    } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return rtfStr;
}
```

Here, I am replacing new line equivalent HTML tags to some special string and replacing back to new line representation chars sequence **\par** in RTF.

If you want to use more effective APIs and you have valid html, you should explore Apache-FOP.

Apache FOP can be used to convert to RTF. Following are some useful links -

http://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/java-xsl.htm#XSL-FO-Java

http://html2fo.sourceforge.net/index.html